# Pre-pending a name to the default name of the angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been experimenting with AngularJS, and I have to say that google has out-done itself. I mean, data manipulation is a breeze and angular is not very difficult to learn. Right now, I'm just going through the source code for angular.

I started doing this out of necessity when I wanted to change the default `{{}}` mustache to something else, since I work with django.

Right now, I want to do something else, which is, how do I change the default name of the controllers in the javaScript of an AngularJS view. I know that sounds a little confusing, so let me explain with an example:

```
<html ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
        <h1> {{ age }}</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
        var Controller = function  ($scope) {
            $scope.name = "Happy Person";
            $scope.age = "30";
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

Now, as you can see, if you name the `ng-controller` as `Controller`, then you have to name your controller the same. This is great, but I want, is that to every name, something like by pre-pended. For example, in this case, the `ng-controller` is called `Controller`, and thats fine, what I want Angular to do is to search for `ang_<controller name>` instead. So for example, in this case, angular would search for `ang_Controller` instead of `Controller`.

How would you achieve this, which parts of the code would you change? This might seem like a silly thing to do, but I want to do this in order to gain a better understanding of how the Angular source code works, and how to manipulate it to my liking.

Comment: If anything remains unclear about the question, please do consider leaving a comment, I will do my best to make things as clear as humanly possible.

Comment: Why mask the controller name?  Why not just have `ng-controller="angController"`.  If you try to mask the `ang` or `ang_` portion from your HTML it'll be confusing for other developers who look at your code to try to provide support or help.

Comment: @Webnet: Its not for any practical purpose, but rather to learn how angular handles it all, and to be able to change angularJS, to what I want it to do, if there is need. In answering this question, you will be telling me, how to change how angular looks for controllers in the script, so that will explain how angular works, which is something that I also want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if what bothers you is to use a global variable, notice that you are not forced to do that at all. For a large application, it's better to use the `controller()` method (as suggested by the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller)):

```js
angular
    .module('MyModule')
    .controller(
        'MyController',
        [
            '$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                // ...
            }
        ]
    );
```

Anyway, IMHO, the best way to do that is to create your own directive, for instance `prependingController`. Its only goal is to define the classic `ngController` directive, but with the correct prefix. Of course, you will use an AngularJS constant ([documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module)) for that:

```js
angular
    .module('MyModule')
    .directive(
        'prependingController',
        [
            'CONTROLLER_PREFIX',
            '$compile',
            function (CONTROLLER_PREFIX, $compile) {
                return {
                    link : function ($scope, element) {
                        element
                            .attr(
                                'ng-controller',
                                CONTROLLER_PREFIX + element.attr('prepending-controller')
                            )
                            .removeAttr('prepending-controller');

                        $compile(element)($scope);
                    },
                };
            }
        ]
    );
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5vdR/)</kbd>